# Como retorna um objeto Json?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Acabei de modificar um exemplo de HTML com Json mas ele é de um tipo array e aparentemente o que eu quero utilizar é um objeto, acredito que seja este o problema.
o json contem essa informação:

{"riotschmick":{"id":585897,"name":"RiotSchmick","profileIconId":956,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1449128440000}}

Acredito que esteja faltanto algo no codigo para funcionar
Aqui está o exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<h1>Meu Projeto</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>
<div id="id02"></div>
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/RiotSchmick?api_key=a15c56d1-fdd7-4da2-ad9c-0f1a6585ac1b";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var out = "<h1>";
    out += arr.id + arr.name + arr.summonerLevel;
    out += "</h1>";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como assim, "tipo de JSON"? Li sua questão e não entendi.

Comment: Ficheiros ´json´ têm uma estrutura única, se mudares já não é `json`. Explica-te melhor, falas de outro ficheiro `.json` com dados diferentes do actual ?

Comment: Ja descobri muito obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ja consegui descobri o problema.
Este Json é um objeto complexo, para funcionar fiz dessa maneira:

```html
    out += arr.riotschmick.id + arr.riotschmick.name + arr.riotschmick.summonerLevel;
```

Answer (score 2):

O segundo "JSON" que você está utlizando não é uma lista, então você não precisa do índice para acessar as propriedades do objeto.

```
out += arr.id + arr.name + arr.summonerLevel;
```

Da uma lida [nesse guia JavaScript que explica o que é e como trabalhar com objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos).

> **Editado:** AP alterou a pergunta, o JSON foi alterado.

## O que é um objeto?

objeto é uma a entidade independente, com propriedades e tipo.

## Como acessar as propriedades do meu objeto?

nomeDoObjeto.nomeDaPropriedade

## Como sei quais propriedade tem meu objeto?

Se você não sabe quais propriedades tem seu objeto em JavaScript, uma opção é imprimi-lo no console do navegador (`console.log('')`), dessa forma você poderá ver todas as propriedades de seu objeto e identificar se é apenas um objeto ou uma coleção de objetos.

## O que é uma coleção de objetos?

É um Array de objetos, ou seja, vários objetos agrupados em um único local.

> No link que citei no começo da respota tem uma explicação bem
>   detalhada e clara sobre o que é um objeto, sugiro que leia e tente
>   entender, caso tenha alguma dúvida, procure na comunidade e caso não
>   encontre uma resposta pode postar uma nova pergunta sempre que julgar
>   necessário.

```js
var obj = {
  "riotschmick": {
    "id": 585897,
    "name": "RiotSchmick",
    "profileIconId": 956,
    "summonerLe‌​vel": 30,
    "revisionDate": 1449128440000
  }
};

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.riotschmick);
console.log(obj.riotschmick.id);
console.log(obj.riotschmick.name);
```

Comment: não funciona...o json é:      {"riotschmick":{"id":585897,"name":"RiotSchmick","profileIconId":956,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1449128440000}} mas eu n consigo pegar ele msm assim

Comment: @Johnner alterei a respota.